# Pandas str split

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_finalexplode['SUPPLIER'],df_finalexplode['Parts'] = `df_finalexplode['ExtSupplierFULL'].str.split('$$',1).str`
```

Ran the code but eg: NdA$$5B-124882G , did not split into 2 columns SUPPLIER and Parts.

Instead it only appear under SUPPLIER as NdA$$5B-124882G , without being split by '$$'.

Seek your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
df[['SUPPLIER', 'Parts']] = df['ExtSupplierFULL'].str.split('\$\$', expand=True)
print(df)

   ExtSupplierFULL SUPPLIER       Parts
0  NdA$$5B-124882G      NdA  5B-124882G
```